# Convertir string a array angular - Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hola buenas tengo un inconveniente
tengo este array que me arroja como string

```
[{TCAD: "[{name:'RURAL',y:0.186838},{name:'URBANA',y:0.805798}]"}]
```

Obtuve el valor de TCAD con el metodo:

```
this.jsonmap[0].TCAD;
```

Como resultado me arroja el valor dentro de TCAD

```
[{name:'RURAL',y:0.186838},{name:'URBANA',y:0.805798}]
```

Quisiera convertir ese string en un Array

```
[
   {
      "name":"RURAL",
      "y":0.186838
   },
   {
      "name":"URBANA",
      "y":0.805798
   }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones. La primera opción, fácil y directa dado que estás usando `angular`, es instalar la librería [JSON5](https://github.com/json5/json5) que te permite hacerlo:

```js
let string = "[{name:'RURAL',y:0.186838},{name:'URBANA',y:0.805798}]"

let obj = JSON5.parse(string)

console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/json5@^2.0.0/dist/index.min.js"></script>
```

La segunda opción, y algo relativamente más compleja, es parsearlo tu mismo. Puedes checar [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086404/string-to-object-in-js) como referencia para ello y te adjunto un posible ejemplo que funciona con tu formato. La idea es modificar la cadena para adaptarla a un formato `json` que pueda decodificar `JSON.parse()`. La ventaja es obvia, no requiere de librerías externas.

Para tu caso particular, solo requieres agregarle comillas a las llaves y sustituir la comilla simple por la doble:

```js
let string = "[{name:'RURAL',y:0.186838},{name:'URBANA',y:0.805798}]"
string = string.replace(/\w+(?=:)/g, (key) => {
    return '"' + key + '"';
})
string = string.replace(/'/g, '"')

console.log(JSON.parse(string));
```

La última, pero la más peligrosa por cuestiones de seguridad es usar `eval`. Checa las [recomendaciones de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#no_utilice_eval_innecesariamente) antes de usarla, aunque realmente la inseguridad depende de la fuente de donde te llegue el `string`. Considera las opciones anteriores antes de usar esta:

```js
let string = "[{name:'RURAL',y:0.186838},{name:'URBANA',y:0.805798}]"
let obj = eval(string)
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: A que tener cuidado al usar `eval()`  puedes revisarlo si te conviene usarlo aquí en [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#no_utilice_eval_innecesariamente)

Comment: Justo por ello menciono lo de inseguro. Realmente depende de la fuente del string. Si es algo que estás creando tu al momento, no hay lío. Si viene de algo externo, o puede modificarse de manera externa, es un NO rotundo.

Comment: @BladimirMedranoVargas en vez de eval que se puede utilizar si es Javascript o TypeScript ?

Comment: @PieroDev de todas las opciones deja eval como última alternativa. Checa la que te agregué que no requiere librerías externas.